# Connection refused trying to connect to server

Tags: python, client-server

I am playing around with a little netcat tool of my own, but I keep getting "Connection refused" and a reference to a specific line, I've highlighted that below.

First I run the server, with the following command:
python Netstatx.py -l -p 9999 -c

Then I run the "client" which tries to make a connection to the server, which is listening on port 9999:
python Netstatx.py -t localhost -p 9999

As mentioned, the above gives me an "Connected refused"-exception, how come?

```
import sys
import socket
import getopt
import threading
import subprocess

# Define globals
listen = False
command = False
upload = False
execute = ""
target = ""
upload_destination = ""
port = 0

def usage():

    print "Netstatx - Net Tool for your convenience"
    print
    print "Usage: Netstatx.py -t target_host -p port"
    print "-l --listen                  - Listen on [host]:[port] for     
                                          incoming connections"
    print "-e --execute=file_to_run     - Execute the given file upon 
                                          receiving a connection"
    print "-c --command                 - Initialize a command shell"
    print "-u --upload=destination      - Upon receiving connection, 
                                          upload a file and write to 
                                          [destination]"
    print
    print
    print "Examples: "
    print "Netstatx.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c"
    print "Netstatx.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=\\target.exe"
    print "Netstatx.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\""
    sys.exit(0)

def client_sender(buffer):

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    print "%s:%s" % (target, port)
    # Connect to our target host
    **client.connect((target, port))** <-- This is failing.

    if len(buffer):
        client.send(buffer)

    while True:
        # Now wait for data back
        recv_len = 1
        response = ""

        while recv_len:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            recv_len = len(data)
            response += data

            if recv_len < 4096:
                break

        print response,

        # Wait for more input
        buffer = raw_input("")
        buffer += "\n"

        # Send it off
        client.send(buffer)

def server_loop():
    global target

    # If no target is defined, we listen on all interfaces
    if not len(target):
        target = "0.0.0.0"

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target, port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()

        # Spin off a thread to handle our new client
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, 
                                         args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()


def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    # Read the commandline options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hle:t:p:cu:",
     ["help","listen","execute","target","port","command", 
      "upload"])
     except getopt.GetoptError as err:
         print str(err)
         usage()

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
        elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
            listen = True
        elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
            execute = a
        elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
            command = True
        elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
            upload_destination = a
        elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
            target = a
        elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
            port = int(a)
        else:
            assert False, "Unhandled option!"

# Are we going to listen or just send data?
# if not listen and len(target) and port > 0

        # Read in the buffer from the commandline
        # this will block, so send CTRL-D if not sending input
        # to stdin
        buffer = sys.stdin.read()

        # Send data off
        client_sender(buffer)

        # We are going to listen and potentially
        # upload things, execute commands, and drop a shell back
        # depending on our command line options above
        if listen:
            server_loop()
main()


def run_command(command):

    # trim the newline
    command = command.rstrip()

    # Run the command and get the output back
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
        output = "Failed to execute command. \r\n"

    # Send the output back to the client return output
    return output

def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    # Check for upload
    if len(upload_destination):

        # Read on all of the bytes and write to our destination
        file_buffer = ""

        # Keep reading data until none is available
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                break
            else:
                file_buffer += data
        # Now we take these bytes and try to write them out
        try:
            file_descriptor = open(upload_destination, "wb")
            file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
            file_descriptor.close()

            # Acknowledge that we rote the file out
            client_socket.send("Successfully saved file to %s\r\n" % 
            upload_destination)

        except:
            client_socket.send("Failed to save file to %s\r\n" % 
            upload_destination)

        # Check for command execution
        if len(execute):
            # Run the command
            output = run_command(execute)

            client_socket.send(output)

        # Now we go into another loop if a command shell was requested
        if command:
            while True:
                # Show a simple prompt
                client_socket.send("<Netstatx:#> ")

                # Now we receive until we see a linefeed (enter key)
                cmd_buffer = ""
                while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
                    cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)

                # Send back the command output
                response = run_command(cmd_buffer)

                # Send back the response
                client_socket.send(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import sys
import socket
import getopt
import threading
import subprocess

#define some global variables

listen  = False
command  = False
upload  = False
execute  = ""
target  = ""
upload_destination = ""
port = 0 

def usage():

 print "Net Tool"
 print 
 print "Usage : netcat.py -t target_host -p port"
 print "-l --listen              -listen on [host]:[port] for incoming connections"
 print "-e --execute=file_to_run -execute the given file upon receiving a connection "
 print "-c --command      -intialize a command shell"
 print "-u --upload=destination  -upon receiving connection upload a file and write to [destination]"

 print 
 print
 print "Examples : "
 print "netcat.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c"
 print "netcat.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=c:\\target.exe"
 print "netcat.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\"" 
 print "echo 'ABCDEEGHI' | ./netcat.py -t 192.168.11.12 -p 135"
 sys.exit(0)



def run_command(command):

 #trim the newline
 command= command.rstrip()

 #run the command get the output back
 try:
  output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
 except: 
  output = "Failed to execute command.\r\n"

 #send the output back to the client
 return output



def client_handler(client_socket):
 global upload
 global execute
 global command 
 
 #check for upload
 if len(upload_destination):

  #read in all of the bytes and write to our destination
  file_buffer= ""
  #keep reading data until none is available 


  while True:
   data= client.socket.recv(1024)
  
   if not data: 
    break
   
   else:
    file_buffer += data

  #now we take these bytes and try to write them out
 
  try:
   file_descriptor=open(upload_destination,"wb")
   file_descriptor.write(file_buffer)
   file_descriptor.close()
 
   #aknowledg that we wrote the file out
   client_socket.send("Successfully saved file to %s \r\n" % upload_destination)

  except:
  
   client_socket.send("Failed to save file to %s \r\n" % upload_destination)



 # check for command execution
 if len(execute):
  # run the command
  output = run_command(execute)
  client_socket.send(output)

 # now we go into another loop if a command shell was requested
 if command:
  while True:
   # show a simple prompt
   client_socket.send("<BHP:#> ")
   # now we receive until we see a linefeed (enter key)
   cmd_buffer = ""
   while "\n" not in cmd_buffer:
    cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(1024)
   # send back the command output
   response = run_command(cmd_buffer)
   # send back the response
   client_socket.send(response)




def client_sender(buffer):

 client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

 try:

  #connect to our target host
  client.connect((target,port))

  if len(buffer): 
   client.send(buffer)

  while True: 
   #now wait for data back
   recv_len=1
   response=""
  
   while recv_len:
    data = client.recv(4096)
 
    recv_len= len(data)
    response+=data

    if recv_len<4096:
     break

   print response, 

   #wait for more input 
   buffer = raw_input("")
   buffer+= "\n"
   # send it off
   client.send(buffer)


 except: 
  print "[*] Exception! Exiting."
  client.close()

def server_loop():

 global target 


 #if no target is defined , we listen on all interfaces
 if not len(target): 
  target ="0.0.0.0"

 server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

 server.bind((target, port))

 server.listen(5)

 while True:
  client_socket, addr = server.accept()

  #spin off a thread to handl our new client
  client_thread= threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(client_socket,))
  client_thread.start()


def main():

 global listen
 global port
 global execute
 global command 
 global upload_destination
 global target

 if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
  usage()

 #read the commandline options

 try:

  opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hle:t:p:cu",["help","listen","execute","target","port","command","upload"])

 except  getopt.GetoptError as err:
  print str(err)
  usage() 

 for o,a in opts:
 
  if o in ("-h", "--help"):
   usage()
  elif o in ("-l","--listen"):
   listen=True
  elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
   execute =a 

  elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
   command= True
  elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
   upload_destination = a

  elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
   target =a
  elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
   port=int(a)
  else : 
   assert False, "unhandled option"

 # are we going to listen or just send  data from stdin? 
 
 if not listen and len(target) and port> 0 :
   #read in the buffer from the cmdline 
   #this will block, so send CTRL-D if not sending input
   #to stdin 
   buffer = sys.stdin.read()

   client_sender(buffer)

 #we are  goin to listen and potentially
 #upload things, execute commands, and drop a shell back
 #depending on our command line options above
 if listen :
  server_loop()

main()
```

I found some syntax errors running out your script ( it may be just from copy past), any way i did my small edits and it's working (knowing i'm under linux)
Your problem may be the firewall is refusing connection on that port, try to check it out